# Service for YouTube oEmbed

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to create a Service in Angularjs to make use of various oEmbed providers including YouTube.

```
...
myServices.factory('YouTubeService', function ($resource) {
    //how can I make the URL part dynamic?
    return $resource('http://www.youtube.com/oembed/', {}, {
        query: { method: 'GET', isArray: true },
    })
});
...
```

The oEmbed URL structure is `http://www.youtube.com/oembed?url=<url_of_video>`

How can I make this service work with any YouTube URL provided by the user? In other words, can I call this Service from my Controller and pass in the URL in some way?

```
YouTubeService.query(<url here maybe>)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go, this should work, I think.

```
myServices.factory('YouTubeService', function ($resource) {
    var youtubeservice = {};

    youtubeservice.query = function(urlProvided){
       return $resource('http://www.youtube.com/oembed?url=:urlProvided', {}, {
         query: { method: 'GET', isArray: true },
       });
    }
    return youtubeservice;

});
```

Invoke:

```
YouTubeService.query(<url here>)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you can access external url like this(may throw cross domain error)

But for your question, why don't you use a service instead of factory like this

```
myServices.service('YouTubeService', function ($resource) {
    //how can I make the URL part dynamic?
    this.getStuff = function(url){
       return $resource(url, {}, {
        query: { method: 'GET', isArray: true },
    }).query();
    }

});
```

And invoke it like

```
YouTubeService.getStuff (dynamicUrl);
```

Comment: You're right - getting a `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` error message. Any ideas getting around this?

Comment: You need $sce.trustAsResourceUrl